# Download in Chrome triggered from excel does not work

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, openoffice-api

Hello every one I just found out that chrome has depreciated download triggered from iframes or sandbox. because of this any download's I trigger does not work as expected inside excel add-in ( Only in chrome ). I think that excel dev team should add the property 'allow-downloads' in their iframe please refer the image to see the properties added in the extension iframe. Please let me know if there
any alternate.

[image]

Chrome depreciation reference link - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/04/chrome-83-deps-rems

Code I have used inside excel add in
`window.open('*url to your file*', 'Download');`

Update - I have raised an issue in office js repo, https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1241

Comment: Try raising this issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @RickKirkham. I have raised an issue https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1241.

Comment: This issues has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Write a batch command as below and save it as filename.bat. Then execute it. It should download the file

```
start "Enter the full path of downloading file"
```